# facebook redirect url contents

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Ok, a new phase of my project rewriting our `FB App` for the new `v4 PHP SDK`. What should the `redirectUrl` look like? Currently, what happens during the login flow:

1) I create a `FacebookRedirectLoginHelper` (derived class), use it to generate the `loginUrl` with the `url` to my app (example.com/myApp) as the redirectUrl.

2) Put that into a nice button for the user to click

3) On user click, the `FB Oauth dialog` comes up, user clicks ok

4) My next page (which will connect the `facebook UID` to an account in our system) comes up - but not within the context of Facebook - basically, it breaks out of the `iFrame`.

I have set the `redirectUrl` to be the `Url` of my application:

```
https://example.com/myapplication/index
```

Looking through various comments, it seems like it ought to be the Canvas Page url from my app settings:

```
https://apps.facebook.com/<my app id>
```

But if I do that, it goes into an infinite loop of just putting up my nice button (from #2) over and over and...

What should be the value for the `redirectUrl`?

Comment: Note: I also tried using the FacebookCanvasLoginHelper to get the FacebookSession, but had the same result - jumping out of the iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are creating a canvas app, users will not see your callback URL. But you should put the URL on your website that fits into the facebook canvas.

E.G.

```
http://www.example.com/facebook/yourappname/
```

Referance http://www.boutell.com/fbhowto/chapter1.html

Comment: Thank you for your page... It became clear to me after reading it that I don't really want a Canvas app after all. We just need/want a clean window to our web-based app, so iFrame is the way to go. Cool. Now I just have to figure that out.

Comment: You can still use facebook connect if you want to use a facebook login method. Which is different than a canvas app.

Comment: I'm good now. I have a  new issue, making a new post. This one is good.